# HtmlAgilityPack c# Спарсить расписание с сайта

Tags: c#, парсер, htmlagilitypack

Вопрос заключается в том как именно спарсить расписание.

```cs
                string url = "https://rsue.ru/raspisanie/";

                using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    var pars = new NameValueCollection();
                    pars.Add("f", "3");
                    pars.Add("k", "3");
                    pars.Add("g", "6");
                    var response = webClient.UploadValues(url, pars);
                    string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

                    HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
                    html.LoadHtml(str);

                    //с этого момента дописать
                    HtmlNodeCollection nodes = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2\"]");
                    if(nodes != null)
                    {
                        foreach(var node in nodes)
                        {
                            var link = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class=\"col-lg-12\"]");
                            Console.WriteLine(link);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Empty");
                    }


                    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: что конкретно нужно спарсить? какой html код тебе вернули?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну для начала, вашей "неточностью" (хоть некоторые пишут как и вы), является то, что вы экранируете двойные кавычки, HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) очень хорошо дружит с одинарными. По этому вы смело можете писать `.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='col-lg-12']")`.

Далее по самому вопросу. Откройте инструменты разработчика и найдите нужную "ноду", через какое-то время вы увидите всю структуру сайта:

[image: Site]

Что мы тут видим?

- `<div class="container">` - основная нода с нужным нам контентом (их там несколько, учтите это!).

  - `<h1>` - название группы.
  - `<h1 class="ned">` - вид/тип недель.
  - `<div class="row">` - контент этой категории недель.

    - `<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" id=""` - отдельно расписание каждого дня.

      - `<div class="col-lg-12" id="nedelya-select">` - название дня недели.
      - `<div class="col-lg-12 day">` - контент дня.

Дальше расписывать не буду, ибо этого думаю будет достаточно для понятия структуры и того, как с этим работать.

Хорошо, давайте теперь по порядку будет получать нужные нам данные:

- Получаем основную ноду:

  ```
  var container = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='container' and child::h1[@class='ned']]");
  ```

Тут из за того, что сайт имеет несколько `<div class="container">`, я добавил дополнительную проверку, которая проверяет наличие в дочернем элементе `h1` с нужным классом, в итоге мы получим ту ноду, которая:

1. Является `div` с классом `container`.
2. Внутри себя содержит `<h1 class="ned">`.

Теперь можем двигаться дальше и из полученной ноды вытягивать все остальное.

- Получаем названия категорий (черные/нечетные):

  ```
  var categories = container.SelectNodes("./h1[@class='ned']");
  ```
- Получаем контент каждой категории:

  ```
  foreach (var category in categories)
  {
      var content = category.SelectSingleNode("./following-sibling::div[@class='row']");
  }
  ```

Мы перебираем полученные заголовки и берем следующую, после них ноду, `div` с указанным классом. Вообще я думаю это все можно преобразовать в `Dictionary` для удобства:

```
var categories = container.SelectNodes("./h1[@class='ned']").ToDictionary(k => k.InnerText, v => v.SelectSingleNode("./following-sibling::div[@class='row']"));
```

Эта строчка объединяет в себе предыдущие запросы на получение четных и нечетных, а также получения их содержимого. Ключом будет название категории, а значением ключа нужная нам div.

Чтож, можем двигаться дальше...

- Получим все дни недели:

  ```
  foreach (var category in categories)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(category.Key);
      var weekday = category.Value.SelectNodes("./div[@id]");
  }
  ```

Тут все просто, из каждой полученной категории, забираем все `div`, которые имеют `id` (нам сайт его выдает пустой). Поняв принцип, смело можем переработать строку формирования `Dictionary`, дописав туда необходимый XPath:

```
var categories = container.SelectNodes("./h1[@class='ned']").ToDictionary(k => k.InnerText, v => v.SelectSingleNode("./following-sibling::div[@class='row']").SelectNodes("./div[@id]"));
```

Тут я дописал `.SelectNodes("./div[@id]")` для получения всех дней недели. Наверно у вас появился вопрос "почему не в одну XPath?", отвечу - я без понятия как заставить его забирать только дни недели внутри указанного `div`, если объединить, то первая категория будет иметь 11 дней недели (все, включая нечетные), а вторая будет иметь только свои.

Ну что-ж, основы я вам вроде показал, дальше я думаю вы сможете без труда сделать сами все, что необходимо.

Напоследок пример вывода названия категории и дней недели:

```
foreach (var category in categories)
{
    Console.WriteLine(category.Key);

    foreach (var weekday in category.Value)
    {
        var name = weekday.SelectSingleNode("./div[starts-with(@id, 'nedelya')]")?.InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine($"- {name}");
    }
}
```

Ну и весь код:

```
private static async Task<string> GetSchedule(int faculty, int course, int group)
{
    var url = "https://rsue.ru/raspisanie/";
    var postContent = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["f"] = $"{faculty}",
        ["k"] = $"{course}",
        ["g"] = $"{group}",
    };

    using var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(postContent));
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

public static async void LoadData()
{
    var str = await GetSchedule(3, 3, 6);
    HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
    html.LoadHtml(str);

    var container = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='container' and child::h1[@class='ned']]");
    var categories = container.SelectNodes("./h1[@class='ned']")
        .ToDictionary(k => k.InnerText, v => v.SelectSingleNode("./following-sibling::div[@class='row']").SelectNodes("./div[@id]"));

    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(category.Key);

        foreach (var weekday in category.Value)
        {
            var name = weekday.SelectSingleNode("./div[starts-with(@id, 'nedelya')]")?.InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine($"- {name}");
        }
    }
}
```

Если планируете и дальше работать с XPath, то советую эту [шпаргалку](https://devhints.io/xpath), очень часто меня выручала.